# Loop colour transition with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, keyframe

I would like to be able to loop a colour transition for the background colour of my website, so it slowly shifts between two subtly different hues as the users browse, to give variation to their browsing experience. I'm wanting something like the following:

```
.background {
  background-color: #00A0D6;
  transition: background-color: 100s;
}
```

But with `background-color` cycling back to `#00A0D6`, then beginning the transition back to `#00B1D7` as soon as it has reached `#00A0D6`. I would also like this to happen automatically, from the moment a user browses to the site.

If possible I would like to do this in vanilla CSS. If not, is there a way to use a Javascript loop to cycle the value in this way? Possibly with the jQuery library? I would like the most processor-efficient method possible which still retains a smooth transition, since this is for an online RPG, which will be doing a lot of other transitions and databasing at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use CSS `@keyframes` to achieve what you want:

```
@keyframes changeColor {
    from {
        background-color: #00A0D6;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #00B1D7;
    }
}
```

Then you use it with the `animation` property in the desired elements:

```
html, body {
    animation: changeColor 100s infinite alternate;
}
```

More on CSS Keyframes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Comment: This sort of works, and it's very useful just as it is, but the transition is instantaneous after the 100s are up. I was wanting more of a subtle shift, like a time-gradient. I guess that's just a question of adding more frames? Or will I find something in the Keyframes docs which will allow me to smoothly interpolate between colour-values automatically?

Comment: You need to use "alternate", like in [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/37631572/6303733).

Comment: @gcampbell is right, just forgot that part. Answer updated.